# python csv writes too many decimals

Tags: python, csv, digits

A well discussed problem, but could not find a suitable answer.
writing a float list of points (n,3) of 3D vectors to a file using code:

```
...
with open(filename,"w") as f:
    csvw=csv.writer(f,delimiter=";",quotechar='"')
    for point in points:
        csvw.writerow(point)
```

gives file content:

```
 0.04471017781221634;0.0;0.999
-0.05707349435937544;-0.052283996037127314;0.997
 0.008731637417420734;0.09949250478307754;0.995
 0.0718653614139638;-0.09373563798705578;0.993
 ...
```

for a million points this is a waste of memory. Using binary coding is not easy to transfer to other programs. So I would prefer a more compact format like :

```
 0.044;0.0;0.999
-0.057;-0.052;0.997
 0.008;0.099;0.995
 0.071;-0.093;0.993
 ...
```

Here decimals are cut off, rounding is preferred.
How can I change or extend the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is "having the correct numbers" a waste of memory? A million 32 bit floating point numbers takes up 4MB. Not even old phones care about that small of a memory footprint, let alone computers and laptops with literally thousands of times more memory =) Also, note that 0.0447 is not 0.044, but 0.045.

Comment: You can convert the float values to strings before writing the rows if csv's default isn't what you want.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Why would native float size matter here?  CSV files are text.  `0.044` is one-fourth as big as `0.04471017781221634`.

Comment: That's disk space, not memory. The post says nothing about disk space being a problem.

Answer (score 3):

[See also][1]

Python has a built in [round][2], which allows you to specify the number of digits via a second argument. So your code would become, assuming each point is indeed just a list of your dimensions like `[0.04471017781221634,0.0,0.999]`

```
with open(filename,"w") as f:
    for point in points:
        rounded_point = [round(dim, 3) for dim in point]
        csvw.writerow(rounded_point)
```

The key point is the `rounded_point = [round(dim, 3) for dim in point]`, which is a list comprehension, where the `round` function gets applied to each `dim` in the list of `point`.
[1]: [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)
[2]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Comment: Good answer. Maybe skip the intermediate var and round inside of writerow: `csv.writerow([round(x, 3) for x in point])`.